# Do multi engines face the torque effect?

Tags: aircraft-design, multi-engine

Do multi engines face the [torque effect](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/dynamics/q0015a.shtml)? What about jets?

Comment: By "torque effect" do you mean [p-factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-factor)? Or some kind of rolling effect due to a high power engine?

Comment: @RonBeyer to be fair, if the OP understand the difference between torque and p-factor, he would not be asking this question.

Comment: I know that the torque effect is the left-turning tendency an aircraft has. Don't know what p-factor is (the Wikipedia explanation is a bit complicated). Any videos?

Comment: With all engines operating or one or more engines inoperative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean the p-factor. If both engines are rotating clockwise, the plane yaws to the right. If one rotates clockwise, the other counter-clockwise, the effect cancelles out and the plane flys straight.

Comment: What about the effect of the two engines operating at different speeds? Is that significant?

Comment: @TannerSwett I think so. The p-factor is directly proportional with the speed of the prop. Now, if one engine operates at a different speed, the plane will yaw into the direction of the faster engine. (Apart from the fact that the thrust is applied asymmetrically)